# Accessing Npgsql Metrics In Code When Using Npgsql.DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

I need to get hold of the connection metrics at runtime in an environment where running dotnet-counters is not possible so I have been searching for information on how to do this in code.

I first checked the npgsql docs and the section there describes the counters and the dotnet-counters tool , but it doesn't describe how to access them in code.

I have found some samples of how people have implemented this using NpgsqlEventSource, but I then found an open bug in the npgsql repo (4798) which describes missing and unpopulated counters when using Dependency Injection (which I am using). This bug is near the bottom of the backlog so it does not seem as if it will be addressed soon.

However, I was reading through a linked mentioned issue that talked about a new metrics api based on OpenTelemetry so I am thinking this will supercede the old EventCounters mechanism at some point soon-ish and might be the reason why the open bug is of a lower priority.

Unfortunately I need to get something working now so I was wondering if anyone knows of a workaround to get the EventCounters code approach working when using DI?